# Javapackager – native packaging / self-contained apps additional information

Tags: java, package, javapackager

I am able to make `native package / self-contained app` but I do not know how to specify additional information such as `vendor name, version number` etc.

Where can I found list of these `properties` and how can I set them for `package`?

Comment: Are you building a exe or what kind of package do you build?

Comment: I am building .exe installer. Oracle documentation – https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html.

Answer (score 3):

```
javapackager -deploy -native installer -Bvendor=name -BappVersion=version ..etc
```

Bundler argument also has vendor so `-vendor vendorName` or `-Bvendor=vendorName`

hope it helps now, but try when you are free

Comment: It is not working but problem is probably in parameters (vendor, appversion). Maybe in meanwhile I will investigate it. I am doing something else at this time.

Comment: okay i have editted  try when you are about to investigate.@Uzivatel828

Comment: How do you verify the `-Bvendor` parameter worked?  Should the vendor name be visible in the `About` dialog box?  I don't see the name anywhere.

Comment: which os are you using? goto programs details or in the control panel in windows find your application and you will see the details below@DemPilafian